# Docker returned a non-zero code: 3221226356

Tags: azure, docker, powershell

I have written following command in my docker file. I am calling this code via Azure pipeline. When I run below command directly inside docker agent then its working fine but its not working when I use from Azure DevOps pipeline.

```
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet" && \
\Projects\setup.exe /VerySilent /Launch=False && \
powershell.exe -Command \
        Remove-Item C:\Projects-Recurse -Force && \
powershell.exe -File \
        C:\PS\UpdateConfig.ps1 &&\
powershell.exe -Command \
        Remove-Item C:\PS -Recurse -Force
```

But when I try to build docker image then I am getting this error message

```
The command 'cmd /S /C setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet" &&     \Projects\setup.exe /VerySilent /Launch=False &&    powershell.exe -Command             Remove-Item C:\Projects -Recurse -Force &&  powershell.exe -File            C:\PS\UpdateConfig.ps1 &&   powershell.exe -Command             Remove-Item C:\PS -Recurse -Force' returned a non-zero code: 3221226356
```

What is the actual cause of non-zero code 3221226356?

I searched on the internet about this code and got to know that this could be a memory leak issue.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You need to append `;` after each PowerShell command before line wrap, not `&&`.

Comment: you mean to say something like RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet" ; \

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?